# ELK - How to pick Time Stamp from Logs file not The Time Stamp of Insertion

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I know there is a lot of Solutions but i can not find the best solution.

I am using ELK **5.x,**I am trying to configure Kibana to depend on Time Stamp from Logs files not from the Insertion Time Stamp

This is Example from Logs files:

```
{"@timestamp":"2018-05-01T00:00:44.191Z","@version":"1","host":"x.x.x.x","lt":{"ln":"abc","mp":"2","lo":x.x,"bi":null,"px":x.x,"dm":"x","py":x.x,"pz":x.x.,"apMac":"x:x:x:x:x:x","am":null,"ap":null,"sc":-x,"ar":null,"as":0,"la":x.x,"si":"x:x:x:x:x:x","lh":null,"pn":2,"po":0},"type":"x"}
```

This Logstash Configuration File :

```
filter {
    grok {
         match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tstamp}"]
    }

    date {
 match => ["mytimestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss +ZZZ"]
         }
    }
```

But Kibana Shows this :

```
No results found 
Unfortunately I could not find any results matching your search. I tried really hard. I looked all over the place and frankly, I just couldn't find anything good. Help me, help you. Here are some ideas:
```

Comment: The format you're using in the date filter seems wrong, use `ISO8601` instead of `dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss +ZZZ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filter {
grok {
match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tstamp}"]
}
date {
match => ["tstamp", "ISO8601"]
}
```

}